# Jquery: on page load fade in and move

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, fadein

Im new to Jquery and im trying to have a div fade in, then move to the left on page load. 
I cant seem to figure out how to chain it.  I can get it to fade in just fine but no move after.  Here is what I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#PageTitle').fadeIn(5000)
});

</script>
```

I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#PageTitle').fadeIn(2000);
    $('#PageTitle').animate({"left" : "300px",}, 4000);
});
```

and several other variations but cant seem to get it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is page title positioned absolutely? Mind sharing your html?

Answer (score 4):

If the `PageTitle` is positioned absolutely then:

```
$('#PageTitle').fadeIn(5000).animate({"left":"300px"},4000);
```

[will work just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/EZTax/)

Comment: Ahh... that was the issue.  I did not have the div marked as Absolute.. (smacks self on forhead).  Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

Your question was a little vague but I would chain it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#PageTitle').fadeIn(2000,function(){
       $(this).animate({"left" : "300px"}, 4000);
     });    
});
```

An example is here http://jsfiddle.net/domjgreen/Hx6rX/

Answer (score 1):

On every animation in jQuery you have a callback function. 
So you should try :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#PageTitle').fadeIn(2000, function(){
        $('#PageTitle').animate({"left" : "300px",}, 4000);
    });
});
```

Check out http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: This worked also.. As noted above the main issue was I didnt have the div set to absolute.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [aos](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) package. First you have to delete unwanted css for using in your own web page.